# Informatica date sync in descending order

Tags: informatica

I need to sync data from 28.02.2022 to 1.04.2020 in descending order. How can I achieve this in Informatica without manually passing the dates?

Comment: can you pls elaborate more ? why process in descending order? can you not read and then order in descending order? You can use parameter file to hold those values.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a sorter based on date before target to write data into ascending order. But if your table is a table this loading process inst important because in DB, data can be stored in any order (unless target is MS SQL Server).

If your target is a file, the order will work properly.

So your mapping will look like this -

```
SQ--> EXP--...-->SRT_keys --> Target
```

if you want to read data in a particular order, you can just add the sorter right after SQ so it processes in a particular order.
So your mapping will look like this -

```
SQ-->SRT_keys--> EXP--... --> Target
```